# I need an alternative similar to System.Runtime.Remoting that is supported in .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-remoting

I have a current software product written in C# WinForms that I'm migrating to WPF .NET 5.0. I've almost got it all migrated, but one of the last projects to migrate is the remoting support for the app. This is intended for remote control from a client in an intranet, NOT Internet.

The current version of the product uses .NET Remoting, however, I sadly have found that this is not supported in .NET 5.0.

I've seen something about gRPC, but can't find anything to show me how to implement or whether there might be something more similar to .NET Remoting to use so that there are minimal changes required.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: _"I've seen something about gRPC, but can't find anything to show me how to implement"_ - _Really_? How about ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/basics?view=aspnetcore-5.0, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-5.0, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/client?view=aspnetcore-5.0, https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=C%23+gRPC+how+to&iax=videos&ia=videos&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DQyxCX2GYHxk, ...

Comment: This is for ASP.NET, not WPF with .NET 5.

Comment: The only difference should be how it's hosted, though. The point being, that the internet is full of gRPC tutorials...

Comment: I understand that. I just can't find an example for any other hosting like TCP/IP. I've done a lot of searches, but we all know it comes down to entering the magical query to get what you want. Everything I see is about ASP.NET Core.

Comment: I just recently learnt, Kestrel can be a TCP/IP Server, too (if that is what you want). I'll have look if I find that article again.

Comment: Here it is. It's also based on ASP.NET, though: https://github.com/davidfowl/MultiProtocolAspNetCore but should be adaptable to be running from a WPF App.

Comment: This could also be interesting for you: https://github.com/cactuaroid/GrpcWpfSample

Comment: Another thing that just comes to my mind: Maybe have a look into [Zero-MQ](https://zeromq.org/languages/csharp/) (I am not affiliated with the project). It's a "Serverless" MessageQueue. Serverless in "" because, it not really is, it just doesn't need to "install" a MQ somewhere. You can just have it running in-process/in-app.

Comment: Fildor, thank you SO much for all of this help! I'll be looking into it.

Comment: The GRPC sample looks like the way for me to go.

Comment: Ah, alas, the Grpc WPF example isn't compatible with .NET 5.0

Answer (score 2):

@Fildor, this isn't really an answer, perse, just posting what I ended up doing for a simplistic approach, rather than leveraging a remoting framework. My remoting implementation always runs on a private network or over a corporate VPN, so security isn't an issue. Thus, I can take a simplistic approach.

What I finally ended up implementing is a simple **TCP/IP Socket** implementation using **TcpClient** class and **TcpListener** that passes **Json** strings to represent a command and the response objects defined as classes. This class includes server API methods, each of which map to the defined API.

I created a class that inherits from **TcpClient** (*RemoteClientSocket*) for the client and another that inherits from **TcpListener** (*RemoteListener*) on the server.This class includes client API methods, each of which map to defined API.

I defined an **enum**, *CommandType* , that includes types for each remote command.

The *RemoteClientSocket* class includes method, *SendCommand()* that is invoked by each of the client API methods after instantiating a *RemoteClientCommand* object, this method takes a *RemoteClientCommand* argument.

The *RemoteListener* class includes methods for each of the remote commands defined in the *CommandType* enum.

I then created *RemoteClientCommand* class that is serialized into a **Json** string and sent from the client and deserialized by the *RemoteListener* object, which maps to the server command. I then created a *RemoteClientResponse* class that is serialized to a **Json** string, which is returned to the client. Each class includes a *Serialize()* and *DeSerialize()* method to serialize/deserialze to/from a **Json** string that is actually sent over the TCP/IP connection.

Lastly, add methods to the *RemoteClientSocket* class for each of the commands that populates the *CommandArgs* object array to send to the server and add methods to the *RemoteListener* class that that executes the server method corresponding to the *CommandType* contained in the *RemoteClientCommand* object.

After the *RemoteListener* executes the command, it instantiates a new *RemoteCommandResponse* object and populates the *CommandReturn* object and the *CommandOutParams* object array, calls *Serialize()* on the *RemoteCommandResponse* object and sends that **Json** string in response over the TCP/IP connection.

When the *RemoteClientSocket* receives the response, it calls *DeSerialize()* on the **Json** response string and unpackages the *CommandReturn* object, if any, and the *CommandOutParams*, if any, before returning to from the client method.

## Here is the code for the RemoteListener:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using RemoteClient;

namespace RemoteServer
{
    public class RemoteListener : TcpListener, IWinCalRemotingService
    {
        private static readonly IPAddress _ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); // Local host

        // Keep track of the threads and create CancellationTokenSource for each
        private Dictionary<Thread, CancellationTokenSource> m_ThreadDictionary = new Dictionary<Thread, CancellationTokenSource>();

        public RemoteListener()
            : base(_ipAddress, Constants.DEFAULT_REMOTING_PORT)
        {
            RegisterCommands();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Start the server
        /// </summary>
        public void StartServer()
        {
            Start();

            // Create a thread for the server to listen on
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartListener));
            t.Start();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stop the server
        /// </summary>
        public void StopServer()
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<Thread, CancellationTokenSource> pair in m_ThreadDictionary)
            {
                // Cancel all of the client threads
                pair.Value.Cancel();
            }

            Stop();
        }

        public void StartListener()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for a Remoting Connection...");
                    TcpClient client = AcceptTcpClient();
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Remoting Client Connected from IP Address:{client.Client.RemoteEndPoint}");
                    Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClient));

                    // Add a mapping
                    m_ThreadDictionary.Add(t, new CancellationTokenSource());
                    t.Start(client);
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }
        }

        public void HandleClient(Object obj)
        {
            TcpClient client = (TcpClient)obj;

            CancellationTokenSource cancelToken = m_ThreadDictionary[Thread.CurrentThread];
            var stream = client.GetStream();
            string imei = String.Empty;
            string remoteCommand = null;
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[512];
            int i;
            try
            {
                while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested && (i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    string hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
                    remoteCommand = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    Debug.WriteLine("{1}: Received: {0}", remoteCommand, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);


                    string response = ProcessCommand(remoteCommand);
                    Byte[] reply = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
                    stream.Write(reply, 0, reply.Length);
                    Debug.WriteLine("{1}: Sent: {0}", response, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                }

                m_ThreadDictionary[Thread.CurrentThread].Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                SystemEventsMgr.AddException("Remoting Server Client Thread Exception", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Remove this thread from the map
                m_ThreadDictionary.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread);
                client.Close();
            }
        }

        private string ProcessCommand(string jsonCommand)
        {
            RemoteClientCommand cmd = RemoteClientCommand.DeSerialize(jsonCommand);
            RemoteCommandResponse response = null;

            switch (cmd.CommandType)
            {
                case ClientCommand.GetAutoInfo:
                    GetAutoInfo(cmd);
                    break;
            }

            return response.Serialize();
        }

    }

    private RemoteCommandResponse GetAutoInfo(RemoteClientCommand cmd)
    {
        int autoID = cmd.CommandArgs[0];
        string manufacturer = "";
        string model = "";
        int year = 0;
        string retString = GetAutoInfo(autoID, out string manufacturer, out string model, out int year);
        object[] outParams = new object[]{manufacturer, model, year};
        
        RemoteCommandResponse resp = new RemoteCommandResponse(CommandType.GetAutoInfo, retString, outParams);
    return resp;
    }

    private string GetAutoInfo(int autoID, out string autoManufacturer, out string autoModel, out int autoYear)
    {
        autoManufacturer = _autos[autoID].Manufacturer;
        autoModel = _autos[autoID].Model;
        autoYear = _autos[autoID].Year;

        return "Success";
    }
}
```

## Here is the code for the RemoteClientSocket:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RemoteClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// IMPORTANT: When adding new commands, do the following:
    /// 1. Add to the command types
    /// 2. Add to the RemoteListener ProcessCommands switch statement
    /// </summary>
    public enum ClientCommand
    {
        GetAutoInfo,
    }

    class RemoteClientSocket : TcpClient, IAutoInfoInterface
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Instantiate and connect the client
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ipAddress"></param>
        /// <param name="port"></param>
        public RemoteClientSocket(string server, int port)
            : base(server, port)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Send a command of input type and receive a response as output type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cmdObject">The Command Object</param>
        /// <param name="inputType">The Type for the Command Object</param>
        /// <param name="outputType">the Type for the return object</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public RemoteCommandResponse SendCommand(RemoteClientCommand cmd)
        {
            RemoteCommandResponse cmdResp = null;
            NetworkStream stream = GetStream();

            Byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd.Serialize());
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            data = new Byte[256];
            string response = string.Empty;
            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            response = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

            // Deserialize the response
            cmdResp = RemoteCommandResponse.DeSerialize(response);

            stream.Close();

            return cmdResp;
        }

        virtual public string GetAutoInfo(int autoID, out string autoManufacturer, out string autoModel, out int autoYear)
        {
            string err = "None";
            RemoteClientCommand cmd = new RemoteClientCommand(CommandType.GetAutoInfo, new object[] { autoID });

            RemoteCommandResponse resp = SendCommand(cmd);

            // Unpackage the return type and output arguments
            err = resp.CommandReturn as string;
            autoManufacturer = resp.CommandOutParams[0] as string;
            autoModel = resp.CommandOutParams[1] as string;
            autoYear = (int)resp.CommandOutParams[2];

            return err;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The WinCal Remoting Client Command Package Containing Json Strings for Objects
    /// </summary>
    public class RemoteClientCommand
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Command Type - one for each remote command
        /// </summary>
        public WinCalClientCommand CommandType { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Command argument object(s)
        /// </summary>
        public object[] CommandArgs { get; private set; }

        public RemoteClientCommand(WinCalClientCommand cmdType, object[] cmdArgs)
        {
            CommandType = cmdType;
            CommandArgs = cmdArgs;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialize the class to Json string for the command
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string Serialize()
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserialize the command object
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="jsonString"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static RemoteClientCommand DeSerialize(string jsonString)
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(RemoteCommandResponse)) as RemoteClientCommand;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The object serialized and returned by the RemoteListener
    /// </summary>
    public class RemoteCommandResponse
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The Command Type - one for each remote command
        /// </summary>
        public WinCalClientCommand CommandType { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The single command return object
        /// </summary>
        public object CommandReturn { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Json strings for all out params - may be empty
        /// </summary>
        public object[] CommandOutParams { get; private set; }

        public RemoteCommandResponse(WinCalClientCommand cmdType, object retObj, object[] outParamObjs)
        {
            CommandType = cmdType;
            CommandReturn = retObj;
            CommandOutParams = outParamObjs;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialize the class to a Json string
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string Serialize()
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserialize the response object
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="jsonString"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static RemoteCommandResponse DeSerialize(string jsonString)
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString,typeof(RemoteCommandResponse)) as RemoteCommandResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you mean you used socket to implemented some class similiar to .net remoting(at least interface is similiar?)

Comment: @LeiYang, yes, that is precisely what I did. It didn't take long to implement it.